# Failed to update to the new Android Material version

Tags: java, android, material-design

I wanted to update the Android Material dependency in my project from 1.1.0 to 1.3.0 and somehow I can´t. This gets displayed:

**ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app**

Comment: Use 1.3.0-alpha01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently material has 1.3.0-alpha01 it's not stable version. You should change dependency to

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01
```